# Unsaved changes in metabox inputs not detected in the block editor

Tags: custom-field, metabox, block-editor

I have added a custom field to the regular WP post type and added a meta box to the post editor as below (it is just an example with trivial checkbox):

```php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_box_my_custom_field' );
function add_meta_box_my_custom_field()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'my_custom_field',                          // $id
        __( 'My Custom Field', 'mycustomfield' ),   // $title
        'display_my_custom_field_meta_box',         // $callback
        'post',                                     // $screen
        'side',                                     // $context
        'low',                                      // $priority
    );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_custom_field_value' );
function save_my_custom_field_value($post_id)
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $new_value = isset( $_POST['my_custom_field'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_field', $new_value );

}

function display_my_custom_field_meta_box(){
    global $post;
    $check=get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $checked_value = isset( $check['my_custom_field'] ) ? esc_attr( $check['my_custom_field'][0] ) : 'no';
    ?>

    <label for="my_custom_field"><?php _e( 'My Custom Field', 'mycustomfield' ); ?>:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_custom_field" id="my_custom_field" <?php if($checked_value=="yes"){echo "checked=checked"; } ?> >
    <p><em><?php _e( 'Enable My Custom Field.', 'mycustomfield' ); ?></em></p>
    <?php
}
```

It works fine in standard WP installation with block editor etc. The only thing that does not seem to work is the detection of unsaved changes.

*When I open the post to edit it, change current setting of 'My Custom Field' and try to navigate out of the page, I do not get the warning. Unsaved changes are lost.*

I have played with changing the priorities, different hooks, but got eventually clueless. Thus, it must be something really trivial that I am missing. Can anybody provide a hint?

Comment: What about when the checkbox is set, but it is not checked?

Comment: The initial status of this checkbox does not make the difference. Neither checking/unchecking does. That is why I suspect the metabox is not registered properly. Or should some "meta field" be registered as well and somehow I should bind metabox to it?

Comment: I mention it because your save function always gives `yes` if it's set, even if it's unchecked, the scenario I mentioned isn't handled by the code, It looks like you assumed that if `$_POST['my_custom_field']` is only set when the box is checked, which may be a bad assumption. You're assuming that if the user unchecks the box, then `$_POST['my_custom_field']` is not set, _are you sure about that?_

Comment: If the goal is to have the editor warn that you have unsaved changes, then you will need to re-implement your field using block editor APIs rather than legacy classic editor metaboxes. The editor can't know there are changes that need to be saved if you aren't using its data store. Add a panel, put a checkbox component in it, update the meta using the data store, and register that meta with the REST API